# Searching a file from a blacklist

Tags: perl

Not sure where to start, but I'm looking to create a blacklist of "bad lines" that search an existing file for these lines..

```
File:
aaaba
bbbab
cccac
dddba
eeewd
pppwp


blacklist file:
ddba
bbab
...
```

Wanting to create a case-insenstive search based upon whats in the blacklist to search similar *lines* to a textfile. Then to create a file of hits.

```
line 2: bbbab
line 4: dddba
```

Treating all characters *,&,|,:,;,#,@,!,^,(),[],/\ as standard ascii chars and searchable if it were in the blacklist/File

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, [index](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) is the appropriate tool:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Usage: foo.pl DATA_FILE BLACKLIST_FILE
my ($data_file, $blacklist_file) = @ARGV;

# Store the blacklist: lowercase, without newlines.
@ARGV = ($blacklist_file);
my @blacklist = map { chomp; lc } <>;

# Process the data.
@ARGV = ($data_file);
while (my $line = <>){
    for my $bk (@blacklist){
        # Print the line if a blacklist item is found in it.
        if ( index(lc($line), $bk) > -1 ){
            print 'line ', $., ': ', $line;
            last;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Perl is not a must, you can use `awk`

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{b[$1];next}{for(i in b){ if($0 ~ i){print}}}' blacklist file
bbbab
dddba
```

Or if they are exact strings, use equality

```
awk 'FNR==NR{b[$1];next}{for(i in b){if($0 == i){ print}}}' blacklist file
```

Comment: awk: run time error: regular expression compile failed (missing operand)
||testlist.test (if added in the blacklist), also if you search for * as a character, it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [`Regexp::Assemble`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp%3a%3aAssemble) to construct a regex from all the blacklisted words, and use that to process the file appropriately :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Regexp::Assemble;

my $file  = 'test.txt';
my $blacklist = 'blacklist.txt';

my $r = Regexp::Assemble->new( flags => 'i' );

# Prepare the regex

open my $bl, '<', $blacklist or die $!;
my @blacklisted = map { quotemeta } <$bl>;

$r->add( $_ ) foreach @blacklisted;
my $regex = $r->re;

# Process the file

open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;

while ( <$fh> ) {

    print "line $.: $_" if /$regex/;
}
```

Comment: Neither works, 1st one seems to just outputs the list, the other won't run.. see the debug: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sBMSHQFN

Comment: @user349418 : It wasn't working because Regexp::Assemble wasn't `quotemeta`-ing the metacharacters. Just tested it now, looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

Make a regex with the blacklist file and test each line in the data file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;

# Load blacklist and make a regexp
sub make_blacklist {
    open my $fd, "<", shift;
    my $bl_re = join "|", map { chomp; quotemeta lc $_ } readline $fd;
    return qr/$bl_re/;
}

# Process the file
my $is_blacklisted = make_blacklist("blacklist.txt");
open my $data_fd, "<", "datafile.txt";
while ( my $line = readline $data_fd ) {
    print "line $.: $line" if $line =~ $is_blacklisted
}
```

This may grab all your memory if blacklist is huge.